# How can I remove a tooltip element when an ul has the class disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

i have a question: how can i remove a tooltip element when i hover on an ul?
I have this html code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12 offset-s4">

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready (function() {
      $('select').material_select();
      $('select').material_select('destroy');  
      $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
  });
</script>
<a id="tool-new" class="tooltipped" data-tooltip="Please select more than one category" data-position="right" data-delay="120">
   <select class="and-or" id="And_Or" name="a_o[]">
      <option value="4" selected="selected">And</option>
      <option value="5">Or</option>
   </select>
</a>
```

I just want to hover the tooltip when the selectbox is disabled. But when the selectbox is not disabled and works good so remove the element  to make that the tooltip has dissapiar. MAY YOU HELP ME?? I'm working with materializecss, a really good framework to designs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have write jQuery on `mouseover` event of **ul**. Whenever mouse goes on **ul** it will hide the tooltip check the code

```js
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('select').material_select();
    $('.tooltipped').tooltip({delay: 50});
});
$('select').material_select('destroy');
$('body').on("mouseover",'.dropdown-content', function(){
    $("#tool-new").tooltip("hide");
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="col s12 offset-s4">
    <a id="tool-new" class="tooltipped" data-tooltip="Please select more than one category" data-position="right" data-delay="120">
        <select class="and-or" id="And_Or" name="a_o[]">
            <option value="4" selected="selected">And</option>
            <option value="5">Or</option>
        </select>
    </a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Still display the tooltip, I want remove the tooltip dinamically.

Comment: how you want to display tooltip?

Comment: Sorry, I had a mistake when I was trying to use your code. All is good. It's working right now. Your code is working. That's good. Thank you!. Tell me something, How can I do to display the tooltip again? What method I need to use?